# Update function to return true if success

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I make the below function returning a `true` if success, meaning if the map reaches the last line?

```
  const setItemTag = (id, tag) => {
    setItems(
      items.map(item=> {
        if (item.id !== id) return item
        if (item.tags.length === 2) return item
        if (item.type && item.type !== tagType(tag)) return item
        if (item.tags.includes(tag)) return item
        item.type = tagType(tag)
        item.tags = [...item.tags, tag]
        return item //if it reaches here, have the `setItemTag` function returning true
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: do you have only one item in the array? why do you use `map`? could you use `some` or `every`?

Comment: if `map` reaches the `return item` for *every* item in `items` or just *any* item? Also, `map` is mutating the original array. You can use a `flag` and set it to true just before `return item`

Comment: @adiga, `map` _is not_ mutating the original array, it’s always creating a new array. However, the objects whose references are passed from the original array to the mapped one are mutated in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable to store the true or false in. Then set it if you reach the end. Then return that.

```
  const setItemTag = (id, tag) => {

    let at_least_one_gets_to_the_end = false;

    setItems(
      items.map(item=> {
        if (item.id !== id) return item
        if (item.tags.length === 2) return item
        if (item.type && item.type !== tagType(tag)) return item
        if (item.tags.includes(tag)) return item
        item.type = tagType(tag)
        item.tags = [...item.tags, tag]

        at_least_one_gets_to_the_end = true

        return item //if it reaches here, have the `setItemTag` function returning true
      })
    )

    return at_least_one_gets_to_the_end;

  }
```